# How to change page size Margins and document language through Word Api ? is any alternate way to do that?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

1. i tried to find word api for that but i guess that is not available
   right now so i thought i can do it by modifying the xml but that
   also didn't work, need to change page size margin and document
   language

```
     await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var paragraphs = context.document.body;

    // Queue a command to load the style property for the top 2 paragraphs.
    paragraphs.load("style")

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
      // let replacedXml=""
      // Queue a a set of commands to get the OOXML of the first paragraph.
      var ooxml = paragraphs.getOoxml()

      // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
      // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      return context.sync().then(function () {
        // console.log('Paragraph OOXML: ' + ooxml.value);
        console.log(ooxml.value)
        let str=String(ooxml.value)
        let replacedXml =ooxml.value
        // paragraphs.items[0].insertOoxml(replacedXml,Word.InsertLocation.replace)
        // context.document.body.insertOoxml(replacedXml, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        var range = context.document.getSelection()
        range.insertOoxml(replacedXml,"Replace")
        // console.log(replacedXml)
      });      
    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> i tried to find word api for that but i guess that is not available right now

The answer is yes. Here is no such api having functionality as your expectation for now and in recent future.

> so i thought i can do it by modifying the xml but that also didn't work, need to change page size margin and document

OOxml is a powerful way to change doc file indeed, but it is only applicable for those very experienced, has a bit unsatisfying performance online and may cause some problems hard to interpret. So in most cases, we don't recommend using ooxml to achieve one's goal actually.
Btw, we suggest to test above code in word desktop app. Only if insuring the correctness of code could support us to go on investigating.

At last, you can submit your request in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform if you really want new api.